# Is seeking pleasure with water on your private part also known as masturbation

Tags: sin, ghusl, masturbation

Is seeking pleasure with water on your private part also known as masturbation. I don't do it with my hand. But when am using toilet I use hand shower  for washing. So after washing of I adjust the  pressure of water and direct it to a certain part I feel something weird and then it becomes  pleasure. So is it also called masturbation and should I bath after it. Evn though there is no  ejection.
As soon as I do it I don't do it till am satisfied bcs I know it's wrong and so there is no ejection but later after sometime it happens.

Comment: As is written this doesn't seem to be on topic. This question is a better fit on a health site.

Answer (score -1):

Idont know if it's haran or not but I know this much that u don't need ghusl janabah until semen comes out of your penis if semen comes out u have to do it but if it doesn't you don't have to do it